# Clarifications on the nehalem processor

Tags: xeon, nehalem

I'm looking at some servers and I'm confused as to the Nehalem processor.

The processor is made by intel, but looking at the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_(microarchitecture)

Why are there so many different sku's for the same processor?

e.g. xeon x5650 and clarkdale 660.

I read about a server which was a 24 core intel Nehalem, given that information, it doesn't really tell me if it was a xeon 5650 or something else.

Answer (score 1):

[Nehalem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nehalem_%28microarchitecture%29) is (a codename for) a type of Intel '[microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture)', and not a type of 'processor'.

It is the successor of (replacement for) the Intel '[Core](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28microarchitecture%29)' microarchitecture.

Microachitecture is about how the processor is designed to perform tasks, and how it interconnects with other parts of the computer.  So the same architecture can and will be used in many different types of processors.

Similar to buildings, you can have a certain type/style of architecture utilized in many, very different, buildings.